# Why Spring Boot inject same HttpServletResponse object to my Controller method for different request?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I wonder why spring boot inject same response object to my controller method  parameter for different request, i use it like follow:

```
@Controller
@Slf4j
@Profile("default")
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    @ResponseBody
    public void getDeviceImage(@RequestParam("serialNumber") String serialNumber, HttpServletResponse response) {
        return balabala;
    }
}
```

I add a breakpoint before return command, and i find that response object's address is same for different request.

I want to write some thing to response.getOutputStream(), and i found there exists previous buffered data.

Comment: Just noticed this - " i find that response object's address is same for different request." What it means exactly by object's address. Which object?

Comment: HttpServletResponse object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i find Response will been reused all the time, and Response's recycle method will been invoked for each request(org.apache.catalina.connector.Response#recycle).
But by default facade&outputStream&writer will not been cleaned, so i make system property "org.apache.catalina.connector.RECYCLE_FACADES" to be "true", after that issue disappears.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpServletResponse` can be used if you need to add some extra meta information like cookies etc. By default even if you don't specify `HttpServletResponse` in the arguments, in typical MVC, model is added to the newly constructed response before propagating to the view.

If you just need to return some response back, say a model or entity or a simple JSON, you don't  have to manually mess the `HttpServletResponse`. Unless you want to dig through cookies or headers etc.,. In your code, if you don't need to care about this, you might probably not need it.

As per the API doc for `HttpServletResponse`:

> The servlet container creates an HttpServletResponse object and passes
>   it as an argument to the servlet's service methods (doGet, doPost,
>   etc).

What you see is probably the default configurations that Spring sets up.

With `@ResponseBody`, the return type is directly written back to response.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody

Comment: I want to write realtime video data in flv format, i do it by write bytes to response's output stream

Comment: You can continue to use the response and add in your case as well. It would be specific only to that request.

Comment: If i request this video data frequently, probably previous buffered data will write to new connection's response stream.

Comment: What happened to me is spring reuse HttpServletResponse object for different request, is it a default configuration?

Comment: I strongly believe is the default config. As stated in the servlet API, response object is created everytime afresh for each request get/post/put etc.

Comment: Do you know how to change this config?